# Is $\mathbb F_q\left(\left(\frac1T\right)\right)\cap\overline{\mathbb F_q(T)}$ separable over $\mathbb F_q(T)$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $x$ be an element of $\mathbb F_q\left(\left(\frac1T\right)\right)$ algebraic over $\mathbb F_q(T)$. Is the extension $\mathbb F_q(T)[x]/\mathbb F_q(T)$ separable?
I think it is true but I did not manage to prove it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer is yes. This has been asked in a more general setting and answered in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287873